# Can React-hook-form create payload with dot in the object key

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

When I register `register("data.name")` the response payload will be something like this

```
{
   data: {
     name: "some value"
   }
}
```

Is it possible to get payload something like with with inbuilt method

```
{
  data.name: "some value"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHF doesn't have functionality, you may have to build this at your app level.